# Transitive routing between two expressroute circuit with azure firewall between them

Tags: azure

I'm trying to find a way to be able to do transitive routing between two expressroute circuits with an zure firewall controlling flows between them.
The two express route circuits are not in the same Azure region, microsoft mainly recommend to use ER Global reach to interconnect multiple express route circuits but in my case i would like to be able to do network filtering between them and from what i understand azure global reach don't even forward traffics to the hub/firewall but forward directlty the traffic between the ER circuits.

I also checked Azure VWan with branch to branch enabled but i'm still not sure if this setup will resolve my issue as even with VWan, Microsoft still recommend Global reach in the documentation...

If you have some ideas or if you think Azure VWan will let me do this fitlering between ER Circuits i'm really interested.

I Already have the ER circuits and the Azure firewall deployed everything is connected in a same azure VNet but i can still do some network changes

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use Global Reach if you want to route the traffic via Azure Firewall.

Azure vWAN with Branch-to-Branch traffic enabled can be a solution, but you must ensure that traffic between the two circuits goes through the Azure Firewall.

vWAN supports integration with the Firewall, but you need to ensure the routing is set up so that the traffic moves through a firewall. you may need to add a couple of UDRs to do it.